# How can I call setState from a different class that is in the same file but different class?

Tags: react-native

I call a function that is in my Homepage class from my ProfileScreen class that is in the same .js file. I successfully did that, but in that function a setState is called, and when the function is called from the other class, the state doesn't change. How can I get this.state.user in HomePage to change from calling the onPressLogout function in the ProfileScreen class?

```
export default class HomePage extends Component<Props> {

 state = {
 email:'',
 password:'',
 firstname:'',
 lastname:'',
 user:true,
 error: '',
 }
 onPressLogout(){
    firebase = require('firebase');
    firebase.auth().signOut()
    .then(() => this.setState({
      user:false
    }))
    .catch(() => this.setState({
      error: 'Logout Failure',
  }))
 }
 render(){
  return <AppContainer>
  </AppContainer>;
  }
 }


class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 Obj = new HomePage();
 }
 render() {
  return (
  ...
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress = 
         {()=>Obj.onPressLogout()}>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  ...
  }
 }
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
Profile: ProfileScreen,
});
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

I get this warning when I run the code and the **this.state.user** doesn't change:

**Warning: Can't call "setState" on a component that is not yet mentioned.**

Comment: handling states from one component to another might require you to use state management libraries (ie. Redux)

Comment: @arjayosma is there no simpler way to do it without using redux

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the function of the parent element into the child element as a prop. Then, you can call it in the child to manipulate the state of the parent class.

Here is an example,

```
class ChangeButton extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <Button title="Change" onPress={this.props.updateMainState}/>
    )
  }
}
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: 'Fatih'
  }

  changeName = ()=> {
    this.setState({
      name: 'Faruk'
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          {this.state.name}
        </Text>
        <ChangeButton updateMainState={this.changeName}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In the code above, we passed changeName function into the ChangeButton element. The Button in **ChangeButton** calls the **function of the parent element** when you press it, which manipulates the state of the main class.

Here is the working code: [**ProjectLink**](https://snack.expo.io/Hk6aveKBV)

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions @David Zhang

Comment: I saw this solution in a lot of stackoverflow pages but how would I implement this in my case with the AppContaniner stuff in the render function of my HomePage class